# google chart api in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, sharepoint-2013

My list name is : Utilization and i'm trying to extract the Title and portal column for the chart, not sure where i'm going wrong but this code is not working. Can some please guide me .

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    // Create the data table   
  
   function drawChart() {
  var datas = GetMyData();

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new         google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(datas, options);
      }
   
   function  GetMyData() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');
    $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "utilization",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='portal' /><FieldRef Name='content' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    var listtitle=$(this).attr("ows_Title");
    var listportal=parseInt($(this).attr("ows_portal"));
    console.log(listtitle, listportal);
  data.addRows(["'"+ listtitle +"'",listportal]);
  
      });
    }
  });
  return data;
 }
    </script>
```

Comment: for this code in console i'm getting this error: 
Object doesn't support property or method 'SPServices'

Comment: sounds like `drawChart` is running before everything is ready but I don't see how. Can you get `SPServices` working first, then add in google's stuff?

Comment: Replace this :data.addRows(["'"+ listtitle +"'",listportal]); to data.addRow([listtitle, listportal]);